# CSS min-height not behaving as expected

Tags: css

[image]

Three boxes, a container, left box and main box.

```
/* Left menu */
.leftMenu{
    width: 200px;
    border:2px solid green;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    min-height:100%;
}

/* Main Content area */
.mainBox{
    border:2px solid red;
    min-height:100%;
}
.mainWrapper{
    border:2px solid white;
}
```

With the HTML:

```
<div class="mainWrapper">
    <div class="leftMenu">
        left
    </div>
    <div class="mainBox">
        main<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    </div>        
</div>
```

My question is, why is the green box (left menu) overflowing outside the wrapper?

Comment: which browser are you talking about? any specific browser or all?

Comment: This is how floated elements work. This will happen in all browsers.

Comment: try setting your mainBox to float left as well..

Comment: Floated elements' dimensions are not reported back to the parent elements as they are not a part of the regular flow of the page. That's why you need to either use 'clearfix' or 'clear' to force the browser to stop the 'flow' and contain the left div inside your outer div.

Comment: Ack! Sorry guys, the height:100px is screwing it up, thats meant to be %, I can't get the left menu to fill 100% height

Comment: Guess I need a faux column huh?

Comment: This question has gotten awfully messy, but learnt a lot thanks for the help.  I'll make a new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve it, either have a `<div style="clear:both"></div>` just before closing the outer div or use clearfix (recommended) like at: http://positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

Answer (score 1):

you must add 'div' element before mainWrapper  with css clear attribute, because you use float:left on .leftMenu.

Here is corrected code:

```
/* Left menu */
.leftMenu{
width: 200px;
border:2px solid green;
height:100px;
float:left;
min-height:100%;
}

/* Main Content area */
.mainBox{
width:100%;
border:2px solid red;
min-height:100%;
}
.mainWrapper{
border:2px solid white;
}
.clear{ clear:both;}
```

and html

```
<div class="mainWrapper">
  <div class="leftMenu">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="mainBox">
      main<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>        
</div>
```

Comment: This will work, but `clear` is not really recommended anymore. Why use HTML to solve a CSS issue? :)

Answer (score 0):

because you have float:left on the left menu(green). You can put overflow:hidden on the container div and the container div will expand like the way you like.