# Mysterious min-height behavior

Tags: css

Try this showcase:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html {
                min-height: 100%;
                overflow-y: scroll;
            }
            body {              
                margin:     0;
                min-height: 100%;
                background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, rgb(230,0,230), rgb(150,0,250));
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, from(#D0F), to(#50A));
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom right, indigo, violet);
                filter:     progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#eb830c', endColorstr='#ffbe0d');
            }
            #container {
                background: #0B0;
                min-height: 100%;
                width:      400px;
                margin:     0 auto;
            }
            #content {
                background: #A00;
                height:     200px;
                width:      300px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="content"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You'll reckon that `#container` won't stretch, despite being set with `min-height: 100%`.

Setting `html, body { height: 100%; }` instead of `min-height: 100%` will solve this problem, BUT then the gradient in the body background won't stretch anymore, and it will repeat instead. You can verify this by setting `#content` higher than your current window height. say `#content { height: 3000px; }`

I could fix it setting `body { background-attachment: fixed; }` but I'd like it to scroll, and this does NOT solve the problem with IE.
So I need to use `min-height` on body and html.

Why doesn't `#container` stretch when I use `min-height`?

EDIT: it's not a solution, but adding a background-color (the same color in which the linear gradient fades) makes the `height:100%` workaround acceptable for IE too. so in IE the background is scrolling and in the others is not, the gradient is linear and in the others' radial.. but it really isn't much of a problem.

EDIT: note that Opera browser correctly interprets the code.

Comment: Check this link, this may help you. But I am not sure about this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792956/css-min-height-not-behaving-as-expected

Comment: nope, that's a issue with the `float` property. not my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### edit

maybe this helps?
http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/XnjRp/3/

I decoupled the gradient and the scrolling by don't scrolling the body but a new scrolling wrapper

---

### original post

min-height does only work correctly, if **every** parent element has a set height, so you need

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Cave: check if mobile browsers have a problem with scrolling and or zooming with this

http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/XnjRp

Comment: "BUT then the gradient in the body background won't stretch anymore, and it will repeat instead."

Comment: @BoltClock I had a little error in the fiddle. Try the new one (edited)

Comment: min-height should work even if the parent has min-height.. and it usually does, but not in this case. setting `height: 100%` doesn't help much, as it produces the problem described in the original post (please read it).

Comment: @user1168006 Why do you think `min-height` will work in other cases, but not in this one

Comment: because it does, of course http://jsfiddle.net/9L5Nh/ . just with html and body it doesn't behave predictively, by the standard. the code works fine in Opera, so it's the other browsers fault for not feeding a correct window height to min-height (or something like that..)

Comment: @user1168006 Ok you are right in this case. But it's got nothing to do with html and body. I missed the point, that if you have heights with percentages, min-height won't work. If you change your `height:800px` to `100%`, you will see: http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/9L5Nh/1/

Comment: well that's obvious, there has to be a parent with a fixed height somewhere higher in the dom tree. when you set html{height:100%;} it inherits the height of the window object, which is it's parent. this works as expected. I don't see why html{min-height:100%;} shouldn't do the same. Just Opera does it right.

Comment: It's in the W3C specs (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-min-height):  If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the percentage value is treated as '0' (for 'min-height') or 'none' (for 'max-height'). So Opera does it wrong

Comment: the point is that THERE IS a parent with fixed height, which is `window` (and this is what allows `height:100%` to work. (thus opera does it right)

Comment: But window is not part of the DOM. There may be the problem

Comment: yes, it's works, it's a good workaround.. albeit i don't like adding structural elements such as divs, just to make the css work :S
thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply do

```
html {
   height: 100%;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, from(#D0F), to(#50A));
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom right, indigo, violet);
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#eb830c',
      endColorstr='#ffbe0d');
   background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

(disclaimer: can't test on as many browsers as I like, sorry.)

By the way, your gradient is in different colours on different browsers, did you notice that?

Comment: yes it's just a test. styling `html` instead of `body` doesn't change a thing

Comment: @user1168006 Whoops, I forgot to copy the `background-attachment:fixed` bit. My bad. See my edited code.